# JS/jQuery conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a "Leaderboard" system, and I have 2 jQuery scripts that seem to conflict with each other. I did not write them I had an old buddy that wrote them for me and I'm not too familiar with js/jQuery.

here is a search bar script one of which that conflicts:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")
    
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });
    
  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','false');
  });

  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','true');
  });

  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

  if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
    else {$('.no-result').hide();}
    });
});
```

And here is the other script that conflicts with the search bar script, this script is for pagination:

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.table tbody').paginathing({
      perPage: 25,
      limitPagination: 5,
      insertAfter: '.table',
      pageNumbers: true
    });
  });
```

What I am trying to accomplish is how to merge them or make them both work together some how.

Comment: could you please share HTML , and when you say conflict then what issue you face in conflict ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the first script in the same pattern of the second.
Both scripts use jquery, but the second one is prepared to avoid conflicts with other libraries.
Check this article for more details:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

UPDATE:

Update the first line of the first script that you've posted, with the first line of the second one. Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });

  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','false');
  });

  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','true');
  });

  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

  if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
    else {$('.no-result').hide();}
          });
});
```

UPDATE 2

Seems that you have bootstrap loaded twice on the page, and the first one is declared before jquery. This is why the error happens.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I think that you can get rid of the 3.3.5 version, and then, put jquery before the bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate you taking the time to try and help, however this is kind of gibberish to me.

Comment: Do you get any console error? If so, can you post it?

Comment: Ok, check the UPDATE 2. I think that it will work now.